# Changing endpoint address for WCF Service for COM object has no effect

Tags: wcf

Originally created a COM visible class library which connects to a service on local machine:

```
<client><endpoint address="http://localhost:8092/MessageService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Messaging" contract="MsgSvc.IMessageService"
            name="Message" /></client>
```

Changed to use service on server in config file but an access application is still trying to connect through localhost. How can I ensure uses the endpoint address specified in the config file?

Comment: Did you restart the application? The config will not be refreshed otherwise

Comment: Recompiled ComObject over new config, but still points to old endpoint. Definitely issue with library as compiled COM object and restarted application.

Comment: Something must be cached or hard coded. Do you have the CCW source code?>